# Is it possible without the use of a third party library to tell how many bytes an integer type is in C at runtime

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am looking to probe at runtime the number of bytes an int is at runtime without using more than POSIX C.

Basically my thought is looking for a way to check the systems limits for UINT_MAX without having my binary rely at that information at compile time. I first thought to try `sysconf()` but that variable was not specified as one that can be used.

edit 1:
To clarify what I am doing is building my own `od` program bases on reading POSIX 1003.1-2017 specifications for the [od](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html) utility.

Specifically from my reading and interpretation of these lines in the extended description.

> The default number of bytes transformed by output type specifiers d, f, o, u, and x corresponds to the various C-language types as follows. If the c99 compiler is present on the system, these specifiers shall correspond to the sizes used by default in that compiler. Otherwise, these sizes may vary among systems that conform to POSIX.1-2017.
>   For the type specifier characters d, o, u, and x, the default number of bytes shall correspond to the size of the underlying implementation's basic integer type

I read that to mean the default value is based on the environment of the running system not the compiler

edit 2: 
`sizeof` was what I was looking for upon reflection I realized that my original thought would not make sense for a statically linked binary in an environment without a libc.

Thanks all.

Comment: Do it at compile-time with [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof). The size of a type can't change at runtime.

Comment: I had not thought of that. If I can't find a runtime solution that might be the optimal solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do it **specifically** at runtime? ["Never put off until run time what you can do at compile time"](http://www.azquotes.com/quote/721061).

Comment: Im basically building my own `od` based on the POSIX 1003.1-2017 specs and this in the extended specifications states for systems that do not include a c99 compiler that " the type specifier characters d, o, u, and x, the default number of bytes shall correspond to the size of the underlying implementation's basic integer type". I read that to mean runtime.

Comment: At run time it is too late. Your compiler has to know that at compile time. You could use [`<stdint.h>` types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) like `int64_t` (it is part of C99 and later standards).

Comment: For things like this, if there is a difference between the environment where the compiler is running and the environment where the program-being-compiled will run, then you are using a 'cross compiler' and compile-time checks will match the environment where the program-being-compiled will run! That might seem impossible but it's 100% true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know the size of an `int` *your* executable uses, then you can use `sizeof` as the size does not change after beeing compiled (even if you run it on another processor).

If you want to know the size of an `int` your program would have if it was compiled on this machine, then the easiest way is probably compiling and running something like this:

```
int main() {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));
}
```

(Or you could grep the include directory on the running machine for UINT_MAX)

If you want to move around `int`'s between different architectures then that's a whole different story.

If that didn't answer it please clarify your intent.

edit:

```
grep /usr/include/limits.h -e 'UINT_MAX' --color
```

works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to achive it in run time you can use the following-

```
unsigned char myIntegerSizeOf(void) {
    int a[] = { ~0, 0 } ;
    unsigned char *a_ptr = (unsigned char *)&a[0] ;
    unsigned char count = 0 ;

    while (*a_ptr == 0xFF) { 
        count++ ; 
        a_ptr++ ;
    }

    return count;
}
```

`count` contains the answer.